# Are customers in braintree saved permanently after creation?

Tags: android, payment, braintree

I am integrating braintree with my android app as a way of accepting payments. Customers in braintree allow you to store and organise payment methods.

This is the way to create a customer:

```
CustomerRequest request = new CustomerRequest()
    .firstName("Mark")
    .lastName("Jones")
    .company("Jones Co.")
    .email("mark.jones@example.com")
    .fax("419-555-1234")
    .phone("614-555-1234")
    .website("http://example.com");
Result<Customer> result = gateway.customer().create(request);
```

When a customer is successfully created like so, is the customer saved somewhere so that it does not need to be created before every payment?

Comment: The customer is stored in braintree and you could use the find customer api to retrieve it in the future https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/find/java You are running that customer request code server-side right? Client side (in the app) would be a security vulnerability

Comment: Ok thank you I will run it server side first.

Comment: If I use google app engine to host my web app / server, if I include a database of my own will it scale or not? @Matthew Arkin

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You can reuse a customer's information in the following way. First, create the customer using the [create](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/java)  method. Next, retrieve that customer's id from the result object, and use the id in a [find](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/find/java) call to retrieve that customer in later use cases. An example of this is below:

```
Result<Customer> result = gateway.customer().create(request);
int id = result.getTarget().getId();
Customer customer = gateway.customer().find(id);
```